# Помогите c Electron + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

Вот созданная чисто для экспериментов страница:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="root">New window</div>
   <script type="text/jsx" src="index.jsx"/>
</body>
</html>
```

И код `index.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

И вот, при запуске приложения страница нормально загружается, но значение, хранящееся в root не изменяется. Что не так?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: что превращает ваш jsx в нормальный javascript?

Comment: надо смотреть, что пишет в консоли

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка ?

Comment: @AlexSlobodyansky А ничего не пишет. Ну или я неправильно запускаю приложение (пишу на Webstorm, запускаю через консоль). Кстати, я пытался создать файл .babelrc (http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation), однако ничего не создается.

Comment: @AynurSibagatullin, то что Вы пишите - не javascript код. Это jsx. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html  Так как это ен javascript код, то прямо в браузере он корректно не выполняется. Чтобы превратить ваш jsx в js - должно быть промежуточное звено. Обычно это babel + webpack. Собственно покажите ваши конфиги вебпака и бабеля (или что у вас там). Если у вас этого нет - работать и не должно.

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Файл .babelrc не создается, хотя я и делаю все как тут http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation

Comment: прежде чем создавать .babelrc, я бы просто подключил react, react-dom, babel через cdn. js файлу прописать тип text/babel

Comment: @AlexSlobodyansky А как подключить? Так?   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.js"></script>

Comment: Да, так и реакт таким же способом

Comment: @AlexSlobodyansky Заработало! Огромное спасибо!)

Comment: Ремарка: для тестового примера подключать бабель реакт и все-все-все через cdn норм, а для уже боевого проекта лучше сделать по фен-шую, через npm и вебпак

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Это понятно, только вот я пытаюсь все сделать как вот тут ( https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/ ) учат, однако ничего не получается. Я уже даже не знаю, что делать.